# Present participle with adverbial meaning in a past continuous sentence

Tags: present-participles, continuous-aspect

> I was leaning against a tree on the hill , **sitting**.

My query is whether or not we should treat "sitting" as present participle with adverbial meaning, or as past-continuous tense.

To clarify , I want to show them in example

> I was leaning against a tree on the hill while sitting.

or

> I was leaning against a tree on the hill and I was sitting.

What meaning does "sitting" in the original sentence ascribe to the overall meaning of the sentence?

Comment: I don't follow the difference you intend to make between the two examples.

Comment: To which of these two examples is the original sentence the most closest in terms of meaning? @ColinFine

Comment: I can't see a significant difference between the meanings of the two examples.

Comment: "I sat, leaning against the tree." is one way to say it. So is "I was seated, leaning against the tree." (I am also a bit confused by the question.)

Answer (score 1):

I was sitting up against a tree on the hill. To me, I think that leaning is implied.....compared to; I was sitting straight as an arrow up against a tree on the hill. By definition, if you are sitting up against a tree, leaning is implied.

Comment: the action of leaning could be realized through sitting or standing.I added "sitting" to imply how I was leaning.@Lambie

Comment: If the focus is sitting up against, the leaning is implied. There is no need to say it. However, there would be a need to say straight to remove the implied leaning.